# Excel, Lock Table row and column sizes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to lock a table's column and rows? 
I have a table and some of my queries and formulas actually extend the length of it.
I want to keep my table confined to a certain row and column limit.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can your clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to keep the table size a certain limit OR have some vba code to resize to specified limit  ie If table changes in size then resize it back to this row and column.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select all the cells in the table and go to Format Cells (`<CTRL><1>`) `-> Protection` and **uncheck** "Locked"

2) Go to `Review -> Protect Sheet` and click "OK"

Comment: Thanks for this, but can I still make adjustments to the sheet while it is protected?

Comment: You will be able to make changes to the table (and any other cells for which you uncheck "Locked" but not the rest of the sheet. Try it!